# Java Swing - Scroll Pane With Custom Graphics

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt

I currently have the code below.

```
public class cRunningView extends JInternalFrame {

    static final int xOffset = 30, yOffset = 30;
  public cRunningView() {
    // Get name;
    super("RUNNING", true, // resizable
            false, // closable
            true, // maximizable
            true);// iconifiable

    System.out.println("##" + "p.getName()");
    // ...Then set the window size or call pack...
    setSize(500, 200);

    // Set the window's location.
    setLocation(xOffset * 0, yOffset * 0);


    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();

}

}
```

My aim is to have a JInternalFrame with a number of buttons and a box/rectangle on half of the screen.

Within this box i want to be able to draw graphics for e.g. Draw oval from x,y to x,y.

I've tried looking at examples but see to get my self more confused than i did to begin. All my code is working e.g. Showing the main GUI window and my internal frame opening but i cant seem to find a good tutuirol/starting point to do graphics within a JScrollPane.

Please note i dont have to use a JScrollPane i just thought i would be a good idea cause it would give the graphics a border round it.

Before anyone moans about the question i think it is valid AND I DONT want the code to be given to me on a plate, i'd rather know and understand what im doing so i can advance my knowledge and be able to help others !

Do i have to make another class and do
    JScrollPane myPane = JScrollPane(graphicsClass)

then do everything with paint() then or is there someway to create a graphic and do it without another class?

If i do :

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    Graphics temp = scrollPane.getGraphics();
    temp.setColor(new Color(1, 22, 33));
    temp.fillOval(60, 0, 120, 60);
    scrollPane.paint(temp);
```

It throws errors.

Thanks

Comment: Do you also want to provide auto scrolling option if the size of graphics you drawing exceeds JInternalFrame size ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't do Graphics in a scrollpane. Also, don't use the getGraphics() method to do custom painting.

Custom painting is done by overriding the paintComponent() method of a JPanel or JComponent. Then if required you can add the panel to a scrollpane and add the scrollpane to your frame. Don't forget to set the preferred size of the panel so scrolling will work.

Start by reading the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html).